# Using edit method in update method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following edit method :

```
def edit
  @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
end
```

and the following update method :

```
def update
  @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
  if @pet.update_attributes(pet_params)
    redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @pet.id)
  else
    render('index')
  end
end
```

could I simply use the edit method in the update method as in :

```
def update
  edit
  if @pet.update_attributes(pet_params)
    redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @pet.id)
  else
    render('index')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller actions shouldn't call other actions. If there is overlap between the two (such as `@pet = Pet.find(params[:id])` this can be done via `before_action`:

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_pet, only: %i[edit update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @pet.update_attributes(pet_params)
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @pet.id)
    else
      render('index')
    end
  end

  private

  def set_pet
    @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters